# installed Ubuntu on external drive now win10 will not boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have tried modifying the grub file manually and using Grub Customizer along with Rescatux,. Nothing is working. I get the error "Microsoft boot manger EFI not found".
I even made a USB with win10, it would not boot the USB. I have change the BIOS several times. The win10 drive does not show up. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You probably deleted Windows. In any case, in UEFI (still wrongly called "BIOS") check the Boot menu and where you see "Ubuntu" try selecting "Windows bootloader manager" instead, save and reboot. That should boot Windows directly, if its system partition wasn't overwritten, of course.

Comment: Ubuntu typically only installs grub2's boot loader into first drive's ESP. If you want to boot external drive from other systems, you need boot loader on external drive. And then you need an ESP - efi system partition on external to be able to install boot loader on that drive. Old bug but never fixed. Several work arounds. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: in the BIOS ,windows is not shown nor in the grub! I don't think I deleted windows when I installed in Ubuntu on a separate external drive. You might example if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

drop to a command line and enter:

sudo update-grub

If grub sees your windows installation it will automatically configure it for you.

Comment: I have tried that also. I first did fdisk -l and it shows the WDC drive disk label gpt. Still did not find the windows 10.  Thanks I'm not sure what to do next. I need to get the windows working again because all my files are there. Thanks

Comment: `all my files are there` -- You can still access them from Ubuntu. You can use Windows installation media to restore the Windows bootloader (search for it in Google/Duckduckgo).

Comment: Based on the info in the question asked how is this an answer?